# How to browse through array in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a code that will browse through an array and when at the very end and the user wishes to go forward, it goes to the beginning of the array. And when at the start of the array and the user wishes to go backwards, it goes to the very end of the array. although i am able to look one way, I can't seem to go the other way continuously? When I enter P, the look works perfectly and will continuously ask. Although when i enter F, the loop stops after one press. Help me make F continues like p!!

```
#declaring array names.
longitude=[]; latitude=[]; messagetext=[];encryptions=[];
input_file = open('messages.txt', 'r')

#read file
lines_in_file_array = input_file.read().splitlines()


#appending the lines in a file to select records.
for line in lines_in_file_array:
     record_array = line.split(',')
     longitude.append(record_array[0])
     latitude.append(record_array[1])
     messagetext.append(record_array[2])

#Stop reading from file
input_file.close()

#This encrypts the message by turning each character into their individual
#ascii values, adding 2, then converting those ascii values back to that
#values character.
def encrypt():
    temporary_array=[]
    for index in range(len(messagetext)):
        x=messagetext[index]
        x=([ord(character)+2 for character in x])
        codedx=''.join([chr(character) for character in x])
        temporary_array.append(codedx)
    global temporary_array


def navigation():
    # Index position
    i = 0;

    # Loop forever
    while True:


     # Get the user's input, and store the response in answer
        answer = input("See Entry? P/F)?")

        # If the user entered lower case or upper case Y
        if answer.lower() == "f":

            # print the message
            print(messagetext[i % len(messagetext)])
            print(temporary_array[i % len(temporary_array)])
            print("")

            # and add to the index counter
            i = i + 1

        if answer.lower() == "p":

            # print the message
            print(messagetext[i % len(messagetext)])
            print(temporary_array[i % len(temporary_array)])
            print("")

            # and take away from the index counter
            i = i - 1


        # Otherwise leave the loop
        else:
            break


encrypt()
navigation()
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "if f, this; if p, this; else break;" The "else" statement ONLY applies to the p, not the f.

What I'm saying is that the part where you check `if answer.lower == 'p'` should not say `if`, it should say `elif`:

```
if answer.lower() == "f":
    i = i + 1

elif answer.lower() == "p":
    i = i - 1

else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
a = ["spam", "bacon", "baked beans"]

# This will never end.
for food in itertools.cycle(a):
    print(a)
```

Comment: It's completely correct, just one thing. It is an infinite iterator. So wont the above code go crazy? and what about cycling in reverse?

Comment: Sure it will. That's why I write "This will never end.". You will have to kill to process.

Answer (score 0):

See if the following works, say `ls` is the list.

```
from itertools import cycle
rls = reversed(ls)
z = zip(cycle(ls), cycle(rls))
while True:
    choice = input("n / p: ")
    n, p = next(z)
    result = n if choice == "n" else p
    print(result)
```

See if it meets your requirement. If it does it's good because there is no indexing operations here. If not please comment.

Answer (score 0):

A few changes:

1. The else: break only applied to `p` test. Fixed by adding an `elif`
2. Rather than starting the index position `i` at `0` start `i` as `None` to allow for a unique test on the first cycle
3. In cycles other than the first increment the index before printing the element. This configures the code to not repeat an element when the user switches between `p` and `n` or vice versa.

   ```
   from sys import version_info
   messagetext = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

   def navigation(messagetext):
       # Index position
       i = None
       py3 = version_info[0] > 2 #creates boolean value for test that Python major version > 2

       # Loop forever
       while True:
          # Get the user's input, and store the response in answer
           if py3:
               answer = input('See Entry? P/F?')
           else:
               answer = raw_input('See Entry? P/F?')

           # If the user entered lower case or upper case Y
           if answer.lower() == 'f':
               i = 0 if i == None else i + 1
               print(messagetext[i % len(messagetext)])
               print("")

           elif answer.lower() == 'p':
               i = -1 if i == None else i - 1
               # print the message
               print(messagetext[i % len(messagetext)])
               print("")

           # Otherwise leave the loop
           else:
               break

   navigation(messagetext)
   ```